# LMB + CTRL disable

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, display-settings, mouse-gestures

My question is about that after pressing  LMB + CTRL I have weird Green Circle (Linux Mint)

It's disturbing me in playing games a lot, because when I'm trying to do something with comibination of this any of my commands are not being done.[image: showcase]

There is an img what shows what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the result of a setting in the desktop environment designed to make it easier to find a small pointer on a HiDPI screen.  Normally it's just the control key that triggers it (that's what pretty much every other system I've seen does), but it wouldn't surprise me if the Mint developers changed it.

If you go into the mouse settings, there should be an option near the top that says something along the lines of:

'Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed'

That's probably the setting you need to toggle (possibly on and then off again).

Comment: Much love. Ty <3